# Javascript check if a div is reached by scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, duplicates

That script works correctly but my alert appears two times also the call of my function "check_page_end" which display my posts two times

```
<script> 

        jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
            if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('#posts').offset().top + $('#posts').outerHeight() 
                - window.innerHeight) {
                alert('end reached');
                check_page_end($('#offset').val());
            }
        });



        });
    </script>
```

Comment: So what's your question? Alerts with scroll events is always a bad idea because the event fires multiple times depending on the scroll amount/speed.

Comment: My question is how the let it be exectued just for one time cuz that duplicate my posts two times

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid duplicate scroll event firings is to postpone the callback to happen a few seconds after the event fires - but first cancel any previously-queued callback.

```
var to;
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    clearTimeout(to);
    to = setTimeout(function() { alert('finished scroll'); }, 500);
});
```

The callback will fire 0.5 seconds after the scroll event fires. If another scroll event fires (e.g. the scroll continues) before that, the queued callback is canceled.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding a new boolean variable it changes it status just when i call my function, here it is exectued only one time

```
<script> 
        window.load_more_content = true;
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).scroll(function(){
        if(window.load_more_content &&  $(window).scrollTop() >= ($('#posts').height())){
            window.load_more_content = false;
            console.log('posts end loading ohers .. '+$('#offset').val()); 
            get_more_posts($('#offset').val());
        }
        }); 
        });
</script>
```